# why is this pickle implementation not working(ie what am I missing)

Tags: python, pickle

In this code i am trying to use pickle to permanently store the values for the new username created when the user creates a new account but come up with logical errors. and the values in the dictionary still stay the same.(I know i am clearly missing something obvious here but I actually don't know what that is)

```
# defining variables
create_username = 0
create_password = 0
password = 0
username = 0

# importing pickle
import pickle

# creates a users dictionary
users = {
    'Joe': 'juk725',
    'Mat': 'axr3',
    'Th3_j0k3r': 'bl4z3',
    'ag4r-j3lly': 'Micr0b3'
}

# sign up (creating new account)
while username not in users and username != 'signup':
    username = input("enter username(type signup to create an account): ")

    # add new user to dictionary
    if username == "signup" or username == "Signup":
        create_username = input("enter a new username: ")
        create_password = input("enter a new password (Your password cannot be the same as your username !!!!!!!): ")

    if create_password in users:
        create_password = input("password taken re-enter: ")
    # then adds the new username to the users dictionary
    if username == 'signup':
        users[create_username] = create_password

    pickle.dump(users, open('pickle_file_name.p', 'wb'))



else:
    if username in users:
        password = input("enter password: ")

    if password in users:
        print("access granted")

    if username not in users:
        username = input("enter username: ")

    if password not in users:
        print("access denied")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never opening the pickled file, and so your code reuses the same dictionary input repeatedly.

You should just create a script to first create the pickle file, then replace the definition of `users` that you have with `pickle.load` method call

```
# importing pickle
import pickle

# creates a users dictionary
with open('pickle_file_name.p', 'rb') as f:
    users = pickle.load(f)

# sign up
```

If you want a readable file, I'd suggest `json` module rather than `pickle`. If you want to more easily query the users, then `sqlite3`

Also not really relevant here, but password hashing would be a good idea to learn for any such project with accounts, rather than storing data in plaintext

Comment: I'd suggest opening the documentation while learning any module https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#examples

Comment: Thanks for that link